# Problem with Xcode user defaults

Tags: iphone, xcode

Trying to change a few things like I had them in Xcode 3.  I can't seem to get user defaults to work.  These are the two changes I tried:

```
defaults write com.apple.Xcode XCCodeSenseFormattingOptions -dict PreExpressionSpacing ""
```

...which should change

```
if (...)
```

to

```
if(...)
```

and

```
defaults write com.apple.Xcode XCCodeSenseFormattingOptions -dict BlockSeparator "\\n"
```

...which should change

```
if(...){

}
```

to

```
if(...)
{

}
```

I also tried various permutations and variants like "\n" and others I found through a web search.  Nothing makes XC4 behave differently.  I can see the change when I use default read, but it does nothing to XC4.

BTW, I also tried something silly like:

```
defaults write com.apple.Xcode XCCodeSenseFormattingOptions -dict BlockSeparator "this is junk"
```

No changes whatsoever in XC4.

Any ideas?

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!